# How to securely save data in a database for a webApp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm developing a web app with `Nodejs`, `express` and `MongoDB`. In the app, each user can create an account and I have to save the data that the user gives to the app inside the MongoDB database.

I'm using some packages like `mongoose` for interact with the database, and `passport`, `passport-local`, `passport-local-mongoose` to facilitate the account creation process, but I don't know if this is the best way to do this.

I'm new to this world and I don't know how to achieve a good level of security, thanks to the `passport packages` i can easily manage the creation of new users,  with an encrypted password in the `user object`,  and their authentication but is it enough?

Here is my user schema

```
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose'),
      mongoose              = require('mongoose');

// CREATION USER SCHEMA
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

//EXPORT FROM USER SCHEMA
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'users');
```

I know that this topic is a very broad topic to talk about, but I would like some tips that can be useful to improve my approach in this area.

Comment: You can set the minimal password length to 8 characters for example. Also you can hash and salt the passwords using [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) for example

Comment: You can use any one of them [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt), [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs), [bcrypt-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs)